# Can not scroll to top when getting the page after login using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one issue. I have one login page when user is successfully logged in and enter into the home page always the page is scroll down using angular.js.I need when user will get the home page scroll will remain top.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the following code when controller gets loaded.

```
$(window).scrollTop(0);
```